# String cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Tags: java, android, xml, parse-platform

Basically I have a login and sign up code for Parse. I'm working off of this [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/). I have:

LoginSignupActivity.java

```
 package com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

public class LoginSignupActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
Button loginbutton;
Button signup;
String usernametxt;
String passwordtxt;
EditText password;
EditText username;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Locate EditTexts in main.xml
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // Locate Buttons in main.xml
    loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

    // Login Button Click Listener
    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Retrieve the text entered from the EditText
            usernametxt = username.getText().toString();
            passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();

            // Send data to Parse.com for verification
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernametxt, passwordtxt,
                    new LogInCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                // If user exist and authenticated, send user to Welcome.class
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        LoginSignupActivity.this,
                                        Welcome.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Successfully Logged in",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "No such user exist, please signup",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
    // Sign up Button Click Listener
    signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Retrieve the text entered from the EditText
            usernametxt = username.getText().toString();
            passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();

            // Force user to fill up the form
            if (usernametxt.equals("") && passwordtxt.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please complete the sign up form",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(usernametxt);
                user.setPassword(passwordtxt);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // Show a simple Toast message upon successful registration
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Successfully Signed up, please log in.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Sign up Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

And my loginsignup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtusername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtusername"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtpassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:text="@string/Password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtpassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:text="@string/LoginBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login"
        android:text="@string/SignupBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to run it I get "string cannot be resolved or is not a field." (String is used as a placeholder). I'm fairy new to Android development. Any help would be great.

Comment: your `LoginSignupActivity.java` code doesnt make any sense

Comment: I didn't want to post the whole thing. But I guess I will. @PavelDudka

Comment: _Where_ do you get this error?

Comment: In my LoginSignupActivity. In theses places `username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
 
        // Locate Buttons in main.xml
        loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);` @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of-

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

write this-

```
setContentView(R.layout.loginsignup);
```

Comment: I am still receiving the same errors.

Comment: Import the R file of your project, remove the "android.R".

Comment: I can't seem to locate "android.R"

Comment: So import this `import android.R;`?

Comment: No, not that R, you have to import the R of your package.

Comment: something like this- "import com.yourpackage.R;"

Comment: I'm going through all the files, but don't have one?

Comment: Then clean-build your app and run.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Now this happens  http://s24.postimg.org/qvgdzfjk5/Screen_Shot_2014_02_07_at_2_55_57_PM_2.png

Comment: Open your R.java in gen package, see if any error is there or not !!

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/dnfm8fgkn/Screen_Shot_2014_02_07_at_3_09_47_PM_2.png No `R.java`

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your project.

Remove private libraries from the 3rd party library project if you have any.

Add to build path your Android v4 library.

Then again clear your project.

Comment: It fixes my current issue. But now the `R` is having issues. http://s24.postimg.org/qvgdzfjk5/Screen_Shot_2014_02_07_at_2_55_57_PM_2.png

Comment: now go to your project properties/Java build path/order & export then press select all then OK.

Comment: keep trying to clear your project.

Comment: also make sure your xml files doesn't include any errors & saved properly.

Comment: When you say clear you mean clean it?

Comment: Yes It means press alt+p+n.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: try by removing private libs as well as android dependancies and then again repeat the process from my answer to my comments.

Comment: Or press Ctrl+Shit+O and clear

Comment: Nothing has happened.